# Ng-class - Active / Inactive button

Tags: html, css, angularjs, ionic-framework

I have a button range with 2 buttons, and I want, when user click on one of them, ng-class add class on button active (My two views are displayed by ng-show/hide).

I have test this, but it's don't work :

HTML :

```
<div class="button-bar">
 <a class="button btn-transpr-left" ng-class="{'activ-btn': isActive1}" ng-click="firstStep()">Acceptées</a>
 <a class="button btn-transpr-right" ng-class="{'activ-btn': isActive2}" ng-click="nextStep()">En attente</a>
</div>
```

CSS :

```
.activ-btn {
 border-bottom: 3px solid !important;
 font-weight: bolder !important;
}
```

JS :

```
  $scope.isActive2 = false;
  $scope.isActive1 = true;


$scope.nextStep = function() {
  $scope.data.step += 1;
  $scope.isActive1 = $scope.isActive1;
  $scope.isActive2 = !$scope.isActive2;
}

$scope.firstStep = function() {
  $scope.data.step = 1;
  $scope.isActive1 = !$scope.isActive1;
  $scope.isActive2 = $scope.isActive2;
}
```

Maybe I make mistake ... Someone can help me ?

Thank's all folk !

Comment: Explain what doesn't work -- is the class not added? Is the CSS not working? Please give more details

Comment: Only the first button have the class applied, but on click, nothing happens ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Part of the issue was that you weren't defining `data` on your scope.  It was `undefined` and *error-ing* out.

```
$scope.data = { step: 1 }
```

I've simplified this for you.  You don't need to really drive this by explicit flags on your scope, rather you can simply do a check to see if the current step value is what you want on the button in the `ng-class` expression

```
ng-class="{'activ-btn':data.step == <desired step value>}"
```

test - http://codepen.io/jusopi/pen/EPyONL

Comment: PERFECT ! Thank's a lot